# ui-bootstrap Datepicker not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a directive for the datepicker, but the popup is not working (neither clicking in the textfield or the button)

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/hUxQASblscbhFZFvWDyN

p.d: the idea is remove all datepicker code from the controller (cause the datepicker will be used in many controllers), so please don't suggest move the open and close function to the page controller.

Comment: I noticed that the datepicker directive doesn't work if you try to invoke it from index.html. I'm still looking but I'd suggest getting that basic example working first, then adding complexity in your own directive.

Comment: angular.module('foo', ['ui.bootstrap']) <-- you were missing the ui.bootstrap in your script.js, that gets the basic example working

Comment: yes i forgot the injection in the module thx, anyway the problem remains. Plunker updated

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure this will get you all the way to your objective, but I think the hurdle you are facing is that you forgot to import ui.bootstrap when creating your 'foo' app.

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZGl0VuJjVF1nliMidaL6

Comment: i updated my plunker with the import, but is not working. Yours is working, did u change something else?

Comment: the only other thing that I can see missing in yours is the datepicker-popup from the input tag. "datepicker-popup (Default: 'yyyy-MM-dd') : The format for displayed dates."

Comment: yes, it was the datepicker-popup (strange, is not needed if u use the datepicker in the "standar" way). Also found another problem, my controler was including a config module that is not defined (its a leftover of the original code in my project). Thx!

Comment: Sure! This issue may be related to the issue discussed here: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/pull/1809

Answer (score 2):

Ensure you have the **is-open** attribute defined in the markup.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="date.format" ng-model="date.selectedDate" max-date="date.maxDate" datepicker-options="date.dateOptions" date-disabled="date.disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" show-weeks="false" is-open="date.opened" ng-focus="date.opened=true" />
```